# How to clear current and previous Activity(AppCompatActivity) , open new Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        Loginactivitynew.class);
 //mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // this will clear all the stack
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(mIntent);
((Activity) context).finishAffinity();
```

> this code i applied fcm service class. this function call time login activity (new activity) corrctly open but latest android devices previous Activity not removed in heap space. please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
val intent = Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loginactivitynew::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i  try but same issue come. login activity correctly open but heap space check time both page showing

Comment: what you mean on heap space?

Comment: recent/overview button  click time (earlier i mention like heap space)